# How can I allow multiple controllers to use one template with controllerAs syntax?

Tags: angularjs

Say I have the following controllers:

```
function MainController() {
  this.hello = function() {
    // does stuff
  }
}

function AnotherController() {
  this.hello = function() {
    // does other stuff
  }
}
```

where controllerAs for MainController is set as `mainController` and controllerAs for AnotherController is `anotherController`. Now say I have the following template:

```
<div ng-click="mainController.hello()"></div>
```

Is it possible to allow `AnotherController` to use this template as well? How can I do that?

EDIT** To clarify, I have two different views calling this template. Whenever the main view calls the template I want the template to be

```
<div ng-click="mainController.hello()"></div>
```

but when the other template calls it I want it to be

```
<div ng-click="anotherController.hello()"></div>
```

I don't want to have two templates because almost everything in the template remains the same except for ng-click.

Answer (score 2):

It is absolutely!!! `controllerAs` Syntax is awesome because it presents more clarity and control when it comes to choosing which variables you are pulling from certain controllers in your app.

In your Controllers Definitions:

```
var app = angular.module('AngularApplication', []);

app.controller('MainAppController', [MainAppControllerFn])
   .controller('AnotherController', [AnotherControllerFn])

function MainAppControllerFn($scope) {
  this.array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
  this.hello = "World";
}

function AnotherControllerFn() {
  this.hello = function() {
    return "Hello";
  }
}
```

In your Template:

```
<body ng-app="AngularApplication">
  <div class="container" ng-controller="MainAppController as main" bindToController="true">
    {{main.hello}}
    <div class="container" ng-controller="AnotherController as another" bindToController="true">
      {{another.hello()}}
      {{main.hello}}
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

I have a [codepen here that you can reference](http://codepen.io/TheLarkInn/pen/PZKJMz).

One thing to keep in mind is that if you want to access a parent controller from your child controller, you will need to inject `scope` into your controller so that you can access the "controller" itself.

So `main.hello` in your controller would look like `$scope.main.hello`.

Comment: Really interesting! I had never thought of utilizing controllers like this. If you're taking the "everything is a directive" approach you would want to make controllers as private as possible, or so I would think.

Comment: Tis true, the example I show here is really not as common for me to implement in my code as most times I am working with directive/controllers/components with isolated scopes. But this can be extremely useful when you aren't in a situation like that. Not to mention if you name them right, and not all "VM", it makes the code more maintainable.

Comment: This is really interesting and I definitely didn't know this but I don't think this was what I was looking for. The fault lies with me for not being specific enough. Say I have two views. A main view and another view. Both of these views use the same template but the main view uses the MainController and the another view uses AnotherController. At the same time, I am using contollerAs sytax so before building the AnotherController, I had the MainController which explains why I have mainController.hello() within the div.

Comment: Now I want it so that if I am calling this template from the main view, it does <div ng-click="mainController.hello()></div> and when this template is called from another view, I want it to do <div ng-click="anotherController.hello()></div>.

Comment: Do you think you could make a plunkr, or codepen that would describe this? You can fork my codepen which has Angular already setup.